# Best pattern to record an incremental integer to a file for recoverability?

Tags: python, algorithm, design-patterns, increment, flat-file

I have a (Python) process that needs to use an incrementing integer for identification purposes. I need to ensure that, should this process need to be restarted, it starts at the next integer in the sequence.

Each night, at midnight, this integer should reset to 0.

I don't have the option of using a database to track this integer.

The simplest way of tracking this integer I can see would be to update a flat file with the last number used. What design patterns should I look at to ensure this operation is both fast and atomic?

Comment: Do the numbers need to be consecutive? If not, use time of day (to some granularity).

Comment: @acfrancis unfortunately they do. I'm using seconds-since-midnight to fudge things for now, but it's not optimal.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the properties of your file system? I would have thought that writing (overwriting) a single int to a 4 byte file was atomic on most systems

Comment: Well, it's not just writing. You have to lock it, read it, use it (if something fails, discard it), increment it, write it, and unlock it.

Comment: @acfrancis If it's only a single process, you can keep it locked and just write to it (and only read when the process restarts).

Comment: @Dukeling: Yes, that does simplify things a bit.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by atomic. It's possible that you can update and store the number, but the process crashes or is restarted before the record that uses the new number is processed further (stored in a file or passed on to the next module, whatever). So when the process comes up again, that id will be missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my KeyValueSqlite package which contains support for atomic integers.

```
from keyvalue_sqlite import KeyValueSqlite

DB_PATH = '/path/to/db.sqlite'

db = KeyValueSqlite(DB_PATH, 'table-name')
# Now use standard dictionary operators
db.set_default('atomic_var', '1')
db.atomic_add('atomic_var', '2')
val = db.get('atomic_var')
assert '3' == actual_value
```